# How to get the entire node with its text content?

Tags: java, xml, dom

For the below XML

```
<employee>
<name>Andrew</name>
</employee>
```

Is there any way to get the entire node with text content

```
<name>Andrew</name>
```

as a string itself by using the DOM parsing strategy ?

Comment: it is possible to get the node names and text contents. but not as tags.

Answer (score 0):

No. When building a DOM the tags disappear and become *nodes*.  There is no such thing in a DOM as "the entire node with text content" that you describe.  After the DOM is built you have this structure

```
node: element(employee)
  |
  +-node: text "\n"
  |
  +-node: element(name)
  |   |
  |   +-node: text "Andrew"
  |
  +-node: text "\n"
```

If you need it you will have to reassemble the string yourself.